# Sending Ajax Request with PhantomJS to a local ColdFusion server

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion, phantomjs

I would like use PhantomJS with highcharts for generate a report. But for my chart, my data are in SQL database. Normally, for generating my chart I use ajax request with a file query.cfc (coldfusion) and my chart works. But with PhantomJS, if I add a function with my ajax request, I have an error in callback - error 404 but I don't no why. It's the same function what I use for my simple chart.

I launch PhantomJS with: `phantomjs --web-security=no test.js`

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

// load JS libraries
page.injectJs("jquery-2.1.1.js");
page.injectJs("highcharts.js");
page.injectJs("exporting.js");

// chart demo
var args = {
    width: 600,
    height: 500
};
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};
page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
    var svg = page.evaluate(function(opt) {
        $('body').prepend('<div id="container"></div>');

        function test() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                url: "query3.cfc?method=test",
                data: {
                    'arg1': 'aee',
                    'arg2': 'ss'
                },
                success: function(year) {
                    var lim_annee = jQuery.parseJSON(year);
                    console.log('success');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                    console.log('erreur ' + jqXHR.status);
                    console.log('erreur2 ' + exception);
                }
            });
        };
        //chart Code
        return chart.getSVG();
    }, args);

    page.render('img.jpeg', {
        format: 'jpeg',
        quality: '100'
    });
    phantom.exit()
});
```

Comment: `404` means the ajax url is not correct.

Comment: Yes I know but my url is good. I tryed with all path but it's the same. My files .js and .cfc are in the same folder

Comment: Check if you ColdFusion function `test` is `access="remote"`.

Comment: Yes my function test is access="remote"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't open a page in PhantomJS, it will stay at "about:blank" and "about:blank/query3.cfc?method=test" doesn't seem like a correct URL. Either use a correct URL to your ColdFusion server:

```
url: "http://localhost:port/query3.cfc?method=test",
```

*or* initialize the base domain in PhantomJS before doing anything else:

```
page.setContent("", "http://localhost:port/");
```

Remember that if you were to open simple local HTML files, you would need to use the "file://" protocol and remove any query string.

Also, loading multiple jQuery versions might break your script.

Comment: I tryed with 
page.setContent("", "http://websiteURL/"); but it's the same. 404 error and if I try with all path in url url: "http://websiteURL/query3.cfc?method=test", i have the same error. I don't know why, my file is really present in my folder.

ok thx for multiple Jquery, i removed one line

Comment: Do you see the resource if you open it in a browser? Are you sure that the ColdFusion server is running?

Comment: Try it with an IP address or "localhost", because PhantomJS doesn't seem to read the hosts file

Comment: yes the website works actually, so coldfusion server is running. ok I try with an IP address. many thx for your help. I post the response when I will try

Comment: I think it's not possible with an IP address, because localhost is the server coldfusion installation. but the folder inetpub is in another disk. with localhost, i can only access coldfusion administration

Comment: It works :) many thx for your help. the website is protect with a login and password, so I moved query3.cfc to the root folder and now my request ajax works